# Error while Querying : The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is too large for its corresponding use

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, db2

On trying to use a select query statement. The input variable has 8 characters just as expected.

I dont know why this error comes for select query because for a select query it will query and if its available it will return else it will retun blank rows.

Hibernate is used. Even in mapping its correctly mapped as 8 only.

This is what i found in log file:

```
Cause = com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is too large for its corresponding use.
```

Has anybody come across this error before? Please suggest me some solutions on why this error occurs..

Comment: can you publish the **query** you are using?

Comment: @ManuPK The query is `select * from TmpSt as cIt "+"join fetch cIt.prp as pst " + "join fetch cIt.tqt as qt " + "join fetch cIt.tceHd as ceH " + "where cIt.empNm = :userId "`.....in code using hibernate

Comment: I think the data is larger than the column can hold?

Comment: I just got this error recently on a query that had been working fine for a long time. Turns out the cause was a network issue. The app server couldn't get to the DB server.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility... This issue can come even in SELECT statement. When the parameter passed into the query is more than the size of its datatype's size, this error will pop-up.

Example:

```
Datatype - CHAR(12)
Search Param: "123456789012345"
```