# Inserting individual values of arrary list in table

Tags: java, sql, database, insert, arraylist

I have an arraylist of strings

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
myList = [url1,url2,url3];
```

I need to insert these urls in 3 different rows in the database.This is how I am doing it.

```
while(myList.size()!=0) 
{
  //get individual values in the array list
  int idx=0;
 String url= myList.get(idx++).toString() ;
  String insert="INSERT into test (url) values (?)";
  prepstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
  prepstmt .setString(r++, url);
  prepstmt.executeUpdate();
 }
```

This goes to infinite loop.
Can someone please help me correct my code? Insert part of code is fine. But I am failing to get the individual urls.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the loop part?

Comment: The code you've shown can't possibly go into an infinite loop.  Please post the relevant part of your **real** code.

Comment: I used a while loop instead of if sorry..

Comment: Your while loop should run forever. Your condition is on the size of the array and nothing in your loop changes this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@niculare give the best way you need to change your code.

but if you don't want to to use for-loop you need to change your if-statement like this:

```
int idx=0;
while(idx < myList.size()) 
{
  String url= myList.get(idx).toString() ;
  String insert="INSERT into test (url) values (?)";
  prepstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
  prepstmt .setString(r++, myURL);
  idx++;
 }
```

or if you not need this list any more use remove method:

```
while(myList.size()!=0) 
{
  //get individual values in the array list
  int idx=0;
  String url= myList.remove(idx++).toString() ;
  String insert="INSERT into test (url) values (?)";
  prepstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
  prepstmt .setString(r++, myURL);
 }
```

you can use listIterator:

```
    ListIterator<String> iter = myList.listIterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        String url = (String) iter.next();
        String insert="INSERT into test (url) values (?)";
        prepstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
        prepstmt .setString(r++, myURL);
    }
```

but I repeat once more: the best way is to use for-loop.

And one more advice. create you list like this:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**UPDATE**

this is one of my examples:

```
public class test2 {

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        myList.add("123");
        myList.add("245");
        myList.add("678");
        ListIterator<String> iter = myList.listIterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            String url = (String) iter.next();
            System.out.println(url);
        }
}
```

Comment: I do not have main() in this class. How do I test this piece of code?

Comment: @smiley change your code to one of this. or you can write test app like in my update.

Comment: I used your iterator method. I initialized int r=1 .            When I run the code, this is the error I see====>   The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is out of range for its corresponding use.. SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=3.57.110

Comment: I think you get this error because you didn't process your preparedStatement. in your while-loop(or in for-loop if you use @nicular example) you need to add `prepstmt.executeUpdate();`

Comment: @smiley also I don't understand why you use r increment. You have simple query with one value and each time your set method must look like this: `prepstmt .setString(1, myURL);`. And you increment it and that why you get this exception

Comment: I get the same error even now.. This is the code I have now.               ListIterator<String> iter = myList.listIterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        String url = (String) iter.next();
        String insert="INSERT into test (url) values (?)";
        prepstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
        prepstmt .setString(1, url);
 prepstmt.executeUpdate();
    }

Comment: please post full stacktrace in your question

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String insert = "INSERT into test (url) values (?)";
for (String url : myList) {
    prepstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
    prepstmt.setString(1, url);
    prepstmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: I have put this code in my method. I do not have main() in this class. How do I test this method ?

Comment: make a main method and call your method there. Since `main` is static you should either make the method which inserts the rows static, or make an object of this class and call the method on that object.

Answer (score 0):

Posting full stack trace:

> [3/30/13 2:35:00:241 GMT-06:00] 00000251 SystemOut     O
>   com.ibm.dw.register.PubHandler handleMessage(String promoter,
>   String topic, String message) com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.eo: The value of a
>   host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is out of range for its
>   corresponding use.. SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=3.57.110

Comment: [look at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137515/error-while-querying-the-value-of-a-host-variable-in-the-execute-or-open-state). There are may be two reasons : first - you trying to insert data to large for url or you have some problems with connection

Comment: I recomend you to close this question(or accept any answer) and write another question. May be someone can help you. i can't help because I don't work with IBM systems

Comment: Thanks!, the post helped. It was size of the database column I had to adjust.