# IBM Worklight 6.0.0.1 - Error deploying a .wlapp

Tags: db2, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I'm getting this unknown error when trying to deploy a .wlapp to a Worklight Server 6.0.0.1, both from Console and through Ant scripts.

My database is DB2.

> Failed to deploy application 'EBCMobileApp-mobilewebapp-1.2.wlapp'.
>   The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is out
>   of range for its corresponding use. SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001,
>   DRIVER=3.62.56

The same error is also returned when trying to deploy the ipad environment's .wlapp of the same app.
The corresponding EBCMobileApp-common.wlapp, however, deploys successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching for the error in Google, I've found the following:

- [IBM APAR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IZ97898)
- [IBM Information Center article](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00302n.html) about this error code
- SO question: [Error while Querying : The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is too large for its corresponding use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137515/error-while-querying-the-value-of-a-host-variable-in-the-execute-or-open-state)

Does this also happen to you in Eclipse, when using the Worklight Studio plug-in to deploy (`run as > build all and deploy`) the app to the local Worklight Development Server?

If it works in the development environment but fails in your other environment, I suggest then to look at how you have configured DB2 in that environment, based on the first two links above.

Comment: In the development environment everything works fine.
The problem is only on the remote production environment where the error is raised during the deployment.
I know quite well the SQL 302 code but what I cannot realize is where I should look for in order to fix the problem. This error is raised by the Worklight server during the deploy operation and the error seems to be caught by the internal procedure implementing the deployment operation. Should I regenerate all the db on DB2?

Comment: I am not sure. You can try this on a test environment and see if it works; if yes, you could then do the same in the production environment...

Comment: Thanks Idan, this solved. The problem was related to the LOB data in the DB that probably weren't correctly migrated during upgrade from Worklight 5.0.6 to Worklight 6.0. I regenerated all the tables containing some LOB columns and now the deploy works also for .wlapp.
Thank you